# UICollectionView prepareForSegue tapping UIImageView by gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer, uistoryboardsegue

I used a `UICollectioView` to load Images with a `NBMutableArray` from web and working well.

Now adding a **Tap Gesture Recognizer** on my `UIImageView` and i will pass the information to other view like a segue identifier example:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if([@"getImage" isEqualToString:segue.identifier]) {
        NSIndexPath *index = [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:sender];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setLinkImg:(arrayCollectionImages)[index.row][@"image"]];
    }
```

In MyStoryBoard i used this:

[image]

if I leave only this function my app go to crash when tap on image.

any body know how can do that?

Comment: Show the code where you are adding tap gesture recogniser to image. May you should call performSegure simply in cell selection method?  Because of this...  NSIndexPath *index = [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:sender];

Comment: I'Am the first time to try use a gesture i linked only from InterfaceBuilder, drag on UIIMageView i asked the code to enable the gesture by segue :)

Comment: You can't get correct index in this case from NSIndexPath *index = [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:sender]; Because sender is UIImageView

Comment: Ok and how can get the Item tapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to add Tap Gesture Recognizer to UIImageView. Just connect 'Triggered Segues' of CollectionCell to your destination ViewController. So that sender will be CollectionCell in 
*- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender* method.

[image]

Comment: Very good approach, but still continue to crash take a look: Unknown class ColletionViewController in Interface Builder file.
-[__NSCFString objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17d6f9e0'
*** First throw call stack:
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: It may due to, you have made some IBOutlet in code and connected it to   some of your UI component. And later you have deleted that IbOutlet from code but you didnt removed connection. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

:)

obviously it will crash.

it  will search the method "setLinkImg" on details page where you need to show this.

so make sure this method is active on details page where you are going to show image.

and again check also the collection  array should contains any value

so in details page where you need to show image should contain

Code should be there in details page

```
- (void) setLinkImg:(id)newDetailItem
{
    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;

        // Update the view.
        [self configureView];
    }       
}

- (void)configureView
{
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.

    if (self.detailItem) {
        your-imageview-object.image = [uiimage imagename:self.detailItem)];

      or any url should set on image view object.
    }
}
```

let me  inform if any need